# Hard to turn kitchen faucet: how to change the cartridge

Tags: faucet

My kitchen faucet is getting hard to turn. I looked online and I think I probably need to change it "cartridge". However, I am not sure how. There is one screw on the bottom of the handle and I am not sure if that opens the faucet to change the "cartridge".

I appreciate any help or hint. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That screw in the handle has to be removed with an allen wrench. Then remove the handle. The chrome dome piece then has to be unscrewed to expose the cartridge. There could be another brass nut to remove too before pulling out the cartridge. Remember to turn off the water before doing any of this. Hopefully there are shut off valves under the sink. If not, then you're looking at turning off the water to the house. Take it step by step and came back if you need more help.